# How can I hide and show actors in python

Tags: python, show-hide, actor, pgzero

So there's this game I'm making and I have the play button as an actor, how do I make it so that when I click it, it disappears? Using pgzero on windows.

PS: I have everything down but the disappearing part.

```
playbox = Actor("playbox")
createbox = Actor("createbox")
customizebox = Actor("customizebox")
choose_quiz = Actor("choosequiz")

mainboxes = [playbox, createbox, customizebox]

playbox.move_ip(200, 250)
createbox.move_ip(200,360)
customizebox.move_ip(200,470)  
choose_quiz.move_ip(0, 0)

def draw():
    
    playbox.draw()
    createbox.draw()
    customizebox.draw()  

def on_mouse_down(pos):
    #i need 'playbox' to dissapear when I click it
    if playbox.collidepoint(pos):
        print("working")
        screen.clear()
        screen.blit("choosequiz", (0, 0))
```

Comment: [Actors](https://pygame-zero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/builtins.html#actors) are objects of [Pygame Zero](https://pygame-zero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), but not of [Pygame](https://www.pygame.org/news)

Comment: Hi there, could you please add a little detail more to your question. Perhaps you could add the relevant code?

Comment: keep actors on list and in `draw()` use `for item in mainboxes: item.draw()` instead of `playbox.draw()`, etc. And then you can remove it from list and it will remove from screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use list to draw Actors

```
def draw():
    for item in mainboxes:
        item.draw()
```

And now you can remove `playbox` from `mainboxes` to remove it from screen

```
def on_mouse_down(pos):
    global mainboxes

    #i need 'playbox' to dissapear when I click it
    if playbox.collidepoint(pos):
        print("working")
        screen.clear()
        screen.blit("choosequiz", (0, 0))
   
        # keep boxes except playbox
        mainboxes = [box for box in mainboxes if box != playbox]

        # or 
        if playbox in mainboxes:
            mainboxes.remove(playbox)
```

And if you add actor again to `mainboxes` then it will be displayed again.

---

**BTW:**

With normal PyGame you could keep objects in [pygame.sprites.Group](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html) and it has function to simply remove object from this group - `object.kill()`